# Differentiate with respect to w

Tags: calculus

$\dfrac{-\pi*A^2(3aA^2+8k-8mw^2)}{32w}$

This is really embarrassing but the important point to make is that I keep getting the same thing.
I'm using the product rule with

$u = -\pi A^2(3aA^2+8k - 8mw^2)$
I get as the derivative of u
as $\pi A^2 16mw$ using the chain rule

$n = \dfrac{1}{32w}$ the derivative is $-\dfrac{1}{32w^2}$

$\dfrac{\pi A^2(3aA^2+8k -8mw)}{32w^2} + \dfrac{\pi A^2m}{2}$

Ive been staring at this for an hour and a half

I know that there should be a four as that last two (on the denominator) Somebody help. This is really embarrassing I'm a uni student

Comment: You're missing a sign in the derivative of $\frac{1}{32w}$.

Comment: I just forgot it

Comment: Like I've written it down I just forgot to put it up all edited properly now (I hope).

Comment: How do you know there should be a 4?

Comment: The numerator of the first term in the final math equation is wrong: the $w$ should be squared, since the numberator is $u$. Notice furthermore that _that_ term partially cancels the second term, which would give a factor of 4.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Willie's comment (which to be honest should say it all):

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\pi A^2(3aA^2+8k -\boxed{8mw^2})}{32w^2} + \dfrac{\pi A^2m}{2} &= \dfrac{\pi A^2(3aA^2+8k)}{32w^2} \boxed{-\dfrac{\pi A^2\cdot 8mw^2}{32w^2} + \dfrac{\pi A^2m}{2}}
\\ &= \cdots + \boxed{\pi A^2m\left(-\dfrac1 4 + \dfrac1 2\right)}
\\ &= \cdots + \boxed{\pi A^2m\times \dfrac1 4} \end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for that I feel quite stupid asking a differentiation question

Comment: Happens! Don't worry about it.